# Django - Update an object with validate_unique as admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, pycharm

```
class MyObject(models.Model):``
    id = models.Charfield(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    somenumber = IntegerField(default=0)

    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        if MyObject.objects.filter(id=self.id).exists():
        raise ValidationError({'id': _('CUSTOM ERROR')})
```

This is my problem: as admin, if i try to edit/update "somenumber" from django admin site, i get the ValidationError

i'm using PyCharm

Comment: `ValidationError` is not useful information, you need to edit your question to tell us what's the error, maybe post the full stacktrace as well.

Comment: I already told you what's the problem, maybe i didn't explain myself.

Comment: From admin site, i want to: 
-create a new object with a validate unique that stop the creation of another object with the same field (using validate_unique, for this exaple it is "id"). 
-update the same object via admin site by editing "somenumber"
i'm starting to think that i have to override clean() and call it somewhere...

Comment: I think you're getting the same object, you should change the filter to avoid search for itself on update.

Comment: @AngelCruijff How can i change the filter on update?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't override `validate_unique`.** It is **not** a hook for users to override. It is a method used and implemented by Django, and you shouldn't touch it.

The proper way to make a field unique, is to add `unique=True` to the field definition:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    somenumber = IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)
```

This will enforce the uniqueness on a database level, and the original `validate_unique` method will automatically raise a `ValidationError` when you try to save a non-unique value to `somenumber`.